# Difference between KafkaTemplate and KafkaProducer send method?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

My question is in a spring boot microservice using kafka what is appropriate to use `KafkaTemplate.send()` or `KafkaProducer.send()`

I have used `KafkaConsumer` and not `KafkaListener` to poll the records because `KafkaListener` was fetching the records as and when they were coming to the topics, I wanted the records to be polled periodically based on business needs.

Have gone through the documentation of `KafkaProducer` https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html

and **Spring `KafkaTemplate`**

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#kafka-template

I am unable to make a decision like what is ideal to use or at least the reason of using one over the other is unclear?

What my need is I want the operation to be sync i.e. I want to know if the published happened successfully or not because If the record is not delivered I need to retry publishing.

Comment: spring kafka is juat wrapper library on apache kafka, you can use either one based on your requirement

Comment: personally, i like the KafkaProducer more than the spring wrapper without adding much complexity. Your requirement can be fulfilled by both using `flush()` (which is available in both clients)

Answer (score 3):

For your first question, which one should I use kafka Template or Kafka producer?

> *The Kafka Producer is defined in Apache Kafka. The KafkaTemplate is Spring's implementation of it (although it does not implement Producer
> directly) and so it provides more methods for you to use.*

Read this link::

[What is the difference between Kafka Template and kafka producer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63808139/what-is-the-difference-between-kafka-template-and-kafka-producer)

For retry mechanism, in case of failure in publishing.
I have answered this in another question.

> The acks parameter control how many partition replicas must receive
> the record before the producer can consider the write successful.
>
> There are 3 values for the acks parameter:
>
> acks=0, the producer will not wait for a reply from the broker before
> assuming the message sent successfully.
>
> acks=1, the producer will receive a successful response from the
> broker the moment the leader replica received the message. If the
> message can't be written to the leader, the producer will receive an
> error response and can retry.
>
> acks=all, the producer will receive a successful response from the
> broker once all in-sync replicas received the message.

[Best way to configure retries in Kaka Producer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65758403/best-way-to-configure-retries-in-kaka-producer/65771716#65771716)